# How to find the quotient space of $ C[0,1]$/$C_{0}[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

How to find the quotient space of $ C[0,1]$/$C_{0}[0,1]$

$C_{0}[0,1]= \lbrace x\in X : x(0)=0 \rbrace$

it will look like that $\forall a\in \mathbb{R}$ , $\lbrace x\in C[0,1] : x(0)=a \rbrace $.

so is the answer: $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: Yes, if you're looking at real-valued functions. $\mathbb{C}$ for complex-valued functions, then, obviously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. To be more formal, the function $\varphi:C[0,1]/C_0[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $\varphi([f])=f(0)$ is an isomorphism (of rings, algebras, etc...), and it's inverse is given by $\varphi^{-1}(a)=[\overline{a}]$, where $\overline{a}:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is the constant function $t\mapsto a$.