# How to find the quotient space $C^p[0,1]$/$C^p_{F}[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

How to find the quotient space  $C^p[0,1]$/$C^p_{F}[0,1]$

$X=C^p[0,1]=\lbrace x : \exists x^{(p)}\in C[0,1] \rbrace$

$C^p_{F}[0,1]=\lbrace x\in X : x^{(k)}(0)=0 $ for $ 0\le k\le p \rbrace$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost the same as question you just asked ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676843/how-to-find-the-quotient-space-of-c0-1-c-00-1/676844#676844)).

A function $f\in C^p[0,1]$ is characterized by the numbers $f(0),f^{(1)}(0),\ldots,f^{(p-1)}(0)$ and by the continuous function $f^{(p)}$, since
$$f(x)=f(0)+\overset{x}{\underset{0}{\int}}\left(f'(0)+\overset{x_1}{\underset{0}{\int}}\left(\cdots \overset{x_{p-2}}{\underset{0}{\int}}\left(f^{(p-1)}(0)+\overset{x_{p-1}}{\underset{0}{\int}}f^{(p)}(x_p)dx_p\right)dx_{p-1}\cdots\right)dx_2\right)dx_1,$$
 so $C^p[0,1]=C[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}^p$. Under this isomorphism, $C^p_F[0,1]$ corresponds to $C[0,1]\times\left\{0\right\}^p$, so your question can be reformulated:

> What is the quotient $(C[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}^p)/(C[0,1]\times\left\{0\right\}^p)$?

and this should be easier for you to solve.